# Code to fetch data from excel in WPF window

Tags: wpfdatagrid

hi 
I want to develop C#.NET base WPF application ,in which I want to fetch data from excel file included in same project as well as manipulate through this data in WPF window.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to convert the excel file to csv from within excel itself and use for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx. Then get the WPF toolkit http://wpf.codeplex.com/ and use its DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns="True" and set the ItemsSource with the output from LINQtoCSV.

If you don't want to convert to CSV you'll have to use something like Open XML SDK 2.0 or http://www.smartxls.com/.